# Liberated Minor Races not available in the diplomatic screen?

Tags: star-trek-birth-of-the-federation

As the Romulans asked it, I took the opportunity to declare war onto the Cardassians. For the most part to get a hold of the Bandi, which were right at my borders. As it's the nature of the Cardassians, they had taken the Bandi by force, so I needed to liberate the system.

So far so good, the Bandi thanked me for taking steps which fit into their future plans...but they are not available anymore as a Minor Race in the diplomatic screen. Their system shows up as not occupied by anyone, they're still there but are not available for diplomatic interactions.

I can remember from a long time ago, that I ran into this problem...do I have to take them by force or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the game (1.02) which never got fixed.

But, one brave modder [called 'Spocks-cuddly-tribble' found the erroneous code and provides a way of fixing it](http://www.armadafleetcommand.com/botf/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=1066), that is, if you're familiar with a hex editor.

Quote from the post of [Spocks-cuddly-tribble](http://www.armadafleetcommand.com/botf/modules.php?name=Forums&file=profile&mode=viewprofile&u=71):

> As speculated here, when signing trade treaties, the entry at
>   [systInfo+3Fh] can prevent the first contact with unknown minor races
>   (although by encounter of independent minor-ships it's still
>   possible).
>
> The bugged code hides in sub_46A770 and can be overridden quite easy
>   by removing of the jump statement at 46A7F7:
>
> In trek.exe at 0x69BF7
>
> change:
>
> 0F 85 7A 00 00 00
>
> to:
>
> 90 90 90 90 90 90
>
> That's all.

According to that forum thread, many mods incoporate [that fix and many others](http://startrekmodding.com/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=1287).

But there's even better news to everyone who does not want to patch there game themselves, the [BotF Patcher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bofpatcher/) will do it for you, and there are many patches already included.

Comment: There are no obstacles so great that they can keep the geeks of the world from fixing old Star Trek games. Fantastic.